# Ajax-валидация на Yii2

Tags: ajax, yii2, валидация

Так как человеческая тупость безгранична, а мое время на диплом нет, то я создам 501 тему по поводу неработающей ajax-валидации.

Есть форма регистрации:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
            'id' => 'reg-form',
            'enableClientValidation' => true,
            'enableAjaxValidation' => true
        ]) ?>
         //тут вот поля всяческие
        <?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
```

Есть контроллер (он не весь, там еще форма входа обрабатывается сначала, если это имеет значение - добавлю):

```
public function actionLogin()
{
    if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        return $this->goHome();
    }

    $this->layout = 'alter';
    //форма регистрации
    $modelSignUp = new SignUpForm();
    $this->performAjaxValidation($modelSignUp);
    if (isset($_POST['SignUpForm'])) {
        //массово присваиваем элементы массива в переменные модели
        $modelSignUp->attributes = Yii::$app->request->post('SignUpForm');
        if($modelSignUp->validate() && $modelSignUp->signup()){
          return $this->goHome();
        }

    return $this->render('login', [
        'modelLog' => $modelLog,
        'modelSignUp' => $modelSignUp
    ]);
}
```

Есть функция performAjaxValidation, написанная с помощью Ctrl+C/Ctrl+V, а не с помощью CRUD (имхо, важно):

```
 protected function performAjaxValidation($model)
    {
        // var_dump($_POST['ajax']);
        if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='reg-form')
        {
            echo ActiveForm::validate($model);
            Yii::app()->end();
        }
    }
```

Смысл нужной валидации - проверка на уникальность почтового адреса.
Есть такое правило:

```
['email', 'unique', 'targetClass' => '\app\models\User', 'message' => 'Аккаунт с такой почтой уже зарегистрирован.'],
```

И ничего не работает (так еще и форма не отправляется, кнопку тыркать бесполезно))). Как только убираю, все связанное с аяксом - все отправляется, записывается, если почта повторяется - выдает ошибку валидации после отправки формы. Однако мне, в связи с особенностями верстки, нужен именно аякс.

Где я накосячила?

Update:
Кстати, при нажатии на кнопку выдает ошибку 505.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: судя по коду выше, вы используете Yii2, а вот это `Yii::app()->end()` из Yii 1, и работать не будет

Comment: @Blacknife Во дела, спасибо, с Yii 1 дела не имела, буду разбираться)

Answer (score 0):

Либо вынесите performAjaxValidation в отдельный экшн и добавьте в конфиг ActiveForm

```
'validationUrl' => Url::to(['performAjaxValidation']),
```

, либо в actionLogin добавьте что-то вроде:

```
$modelSignUp = new SignUpForm();
if(\Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $modelSignUp->load(\Yii::$app->request->post())){
    \Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    return ActiveForm::validate($modelSignUp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Я еще оборачиваю форму

```
                <?php Pjax::begin();?>
                <?php Pjax::end();?>
```

а в обработчике ничего лишнего не добавляю кроме isAjax(пример товарища выше), просто обрабатываю как обычную форму.